# Forced to file W-9 even not passing Substantial Presence Test

Tags: united-states, income-tax, irs, non-resident, tax-residency

I just moved to the US in September.  Because I receive salary in the US, have a US address and US driver's license and everything, Fidelity, where I have a company stock plan account, my bank, and my broker all made me file W-9 and certify as a US tax resident.  However I will never meet the Substantial Presence Test this year.

Can I file as a tax resident for this year even I don't pass the Green Card Test or the Substantial Presence Test?

Or if I file as a non-resident, will it be a problem since I filed W-9's with these financial institutions claiming to be a resident?

Comment: You can likely choose to become resident (at least for the latter part of the year) by using the First-Year Choice. If you are married, you can then choose to become resident for the whole year if you file jointly.

Comment: For details see chapter 1 of [publication 519 on the IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/publications) -- based on past performance, the 2019 version won't be available until Feb. 2020, but AFAIK it shouldn't have any significant changes.

Comment: You have all rights to submit W8 to your broker. Your bank/broker may request documents to complete the curing process. But they should not force you to fill W9 if you have enough proof for non resident of US.